# Determine recurrent states via First Return Probability

Tags: markov-process

I have the following question. It's about transient and recurrent states in Markov Chains. I know when a state is one or the other, but there is one thing I can't figure out or understand.
We have learned that the sum of the First Return Probabilites (FRP) must be = 1 for a state to be recurrent, otherwise it is transient (see Figure 1).

In my example below both states should be recurrent, but if I calculate the First Return Probability for state 1 (a time step) I get 0.5. The others are irrelevant because we already had our First Return. So the sum of the FRP = 0.5 so < 1. But with that it would not be recurrent anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Figure 1:
[image]

Example:
[image]

Comment: Why $f_{11}^{(2)} = 0$?  It is clearly greater than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake on evaluating $f_{11}^{(2)}$, which should be
\begin{align}
P[X_2 = 1, X_1 =  2 | X_0 = 1] = p_{12}p_{21} = \frac{1}{2} \times 1 = 
\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

For $n \geq 3$, it indeed holds that $f_{11}^{(n)} = 0$, as once the chain visits the state $2$, it for sure will return to the state $1$ in the next step.  Therefore,
\begin{align}
f_{11} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty f_{11}^{(n)} = f_{11}^{(1)} + f_{11}^{(2)} = 
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1, 
\end{align}
showing that the state $1$ is recurrent.

P.S., The "Figure 1" in your post seems irrelevant and should be deleted.